# Looking for metric to measure linear and constrained relationship between 2 variables

Tags: correlation, skewness, metric

Data are 2D x-y pairs, both of which have [0-1] possible range. I need to calculate how well these data fit a linear relationship, where the intercept is 0 and the slope is 1. In other words, a "perfect" metric score should be achieved if the data form a straight line between (0,0) and (1,1), and always worse than this otherwise.

The data points are skewed such that most (~98%) are in the range (0.95,0.95)-(1,1). However, I am much more interested in the shape and slope of the scatterplot, rather than how well the points are correlated overall. Gaps may be present in the data on either axis, and there are 100s to thousands of data points. Variance occurs in y-variable, but does not follow any standard distribution shape.

What single-valued metric could I use to measure how well the shape of the scatterplot fits the ideal linear relationship, while remaining unaffected by the huge skew in values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a concordance correlation between $y$ and $x$. This measures agreement between $y$ and $x$, not correlation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient

Comment: The concordance correlation isn't perfect, but it's far better than any of the other measurements I've tried. Just ran some tests with it and I think in combination with RMSE it gives me enough data to work with. I'd be interested if there are any similar metrics as well, but thanks for introducing me to a new statistic.

Comment: What's wrong with it? I have no axe to grind here, as I didn't invent it and even if I did you should use it only if fit for purpose, but I am curious about your precise objections. In several single-authored or joint publications using it we have also recommended looking at something like RMSE as well.

Comment: I found that it is more sensitive to changes to values at the extreme ranges. For example:
(0,0), (0.5,0.6), (1,1) gives 0.9901, and
(0,0.1), (0.5,0.5), (1,1) gives 0.9890.
Both sets have a single point deviating the same amount from the diagonal, but give different results. Like I said this is not a deal-breaker, but something to keep in mind.